# Why can't I access HTTPS websites that use a self-signed SSL certificate?

Tags: certificate

I am having trouble accessing a friend's webserver, which uses a self-signed SSL certificate to encrypt communication through HTTPS.

I keep on getting the security warning asking me if I want to proceed every time I go to a new page and some pages do not work at all.

Is there anything that can be done about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option for self-signed certificates is to email yourself with the .cer file as an attachment. When you open the attachment on the phone it will install and you should see a message reading "Your certificates were installed. Your phone successfully added one or more certificates." After that I believe you have to restart the phone for it to take effect.

Comment: On a side note, do you know how one would remove a certificate added this way?

Answer (score 4):

I use Class 1 SSL certificates from [StartSSL](http://www.startcom.org/) on some of my servers, to encrypt communication when using server administration web apps.

While StartSSL certificates are recognised by all the major desktop browsers, they do not seem to be on the root certificate authority list for IE on Windows Phone, so I could not access these admin sites.

To fix the problem I had to import the CA cert for StartSSL by simply navigating to it on the phone ([link](http://www.startssl.com/certs/ca.pem)), which then gives you the option to import the certificate.

To do this with a self-signed cert, place the certificate on a webserver and navigate to it.

Comment: I've not actually tested this with self-signed certificates, but I cannot see why it would not work in the same way, but I still need somebody to confirm that it works.  I do actually have a friend using a self-signed certificate, but I haven't got him to make it available on the webserver yet.

Comment: Update: StartSSL certs seem to be accepted with no problems on WP8.