# Can I view SSL certificate details?

Tags: security, certificate, internet-explorer

It's nice that IE9 shows a lock icon for a site that uses SSL to encrypt traffic, but I would like to at least make sure it's been issued to the site I intended to visit, and that I haven't been tricked into an encrypted connection on a phishing site.

Is there a way to view information about a site's SSL certificate?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think the phone will accept any cert that doesn't match the domain. I don't think it will even load the page.

Answer (score 7):

As of now, you can not view the cert, but I think you are going to be pretty safe. Via [info.ssl.com](http://info.ssl.com/article.aspx?id=10241) (emphasis mine)

> Typically an SSL Certificate will contain your domain name, your
>   company name, your address, your city, your state and your country. It
>   will also contain the expiration date of the Certificate and details
>   of the Certification Authority responsible for the issuance of the
>   Certificate. **When a browser connects to a secure site it will
>   retrieve the site's SSL Certificate and check** that it has not
>   expired, it has been issued by a Certification Authority the browser
>   trusts, and **that it is being used by the website for which it has
>   been issued**. If it fails on any one of these checks the browser will
>   display a warning to the end user letting them know that the site is
>   not secured by SSL.

Now, I have *personally* never seen an invalid cert on the phone, but [Why can't I access HTTPS websites that use a self-signed SSL certificate?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/229/why-cant-i-access-https-websites-that-use-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate) tells us you do get an error.

Now, Your best line of defense is going to be you. A phishing attempt isn't going to have the cert for paypal.com. What they will do it create a URL that *looks like* paypal, have the cert issued to that, and hope you don't notice.

For example, they might use paypa1.com, **and** have a cert issued there to look legit. Upon closer inspection you will notice the URL is wrong, and should back out.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free app called [**SSL Cert Monitor**](http://goo.gl/haZDF), which lets you check the domain, issuer and expiration date of SSL certificates.